# Is $x_i(t+1)=|S_i(t)|^{-1}\sum_{j\in S_i(t)} x_j\quad i=1,\dots,n$ a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $x_i(t)\in\mathbb [0,1]$ for $i=1,\dots, n$, with $n,t\in\mathbb N$. Let us consider the set
$$S_i(t):=\left\{1\leq j\leq n \Bigl| \, |x_i(t)-x_j(t)|<\frac12\right\}$$
I'm trying to understand if the following system
$$x_i(t+1)=|S_i(t)|^{-1}\sum_{j\in S_i(t)} x_j\quad i=1,\dots,n$$
(where $|\cdot|$ for a finite set denotes the number of elements) is linear or not in $x_1,\dots,x_n$.

What do you think?

Comment: Is your $t$ a parameter, where does it come from? Also, what do you mean with $x_i(t)$?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your definition of linear, I don't see how this could possibly be linear, given that $|S_i(t)|$ isn't even continuous in $x_i$. Suppose you have $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1/4$. Then $|S_1(t)| = 2$. Now translate $x_2\rightarrow x_2+1$. Then $|S_1(t)|=1$.

Comment: @AlexR. Thank you, but I don't understand why your example would prove the nonlinearity of the system...

Comment: @zzuussee, I'm sorry I've updated the post